# Dynamic selector in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

I require in a form for to be able to show one selection based on another.

I have the following db schema :

```
order <-->> line_items <<-->> product <-->> campaign <br>
order <<--> customer
```

I have the following form :

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs I18n.t("New Order") do
      f.input :customer, :collection => Customer.where(:id => order.customer_id).map{ |customer|     [customer. FirstName + ' ' + customer.LastName, customer.id] }
    end

      f.has_many :line_items do |app_f|
        app_f.input :quantity

        #some code that show campaign to filter :product_id

        app_f.input :product_id, :as => :select, :collection => Product.all.map{ |product| [product.name, product.id] }
          if app_f.object.id
            app_f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => I18n.t("Delete")
          end
          app_f.form_buffers.last # to avoid bug with nil possibly being returned from the above
      end
    end
  f.actions
 end
```

I need here to show a campaign selector that filter a product selector to show product based on their campaign in the nested form. (similar to having a product category filter)

Any idea how to do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Once your form reaches that level of complexity, I'd recommend replacing it with a custom template - [Formtastic will only get you so far](http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html), unfortunately.

In a custom form, you could use jQuery to set the options in the product select to reflect the right values for the campaign - or even drop the product select into a partial and reload it via ajax when the campaign select is changed.

Comment: Thanks @SimonHildebrandt for the heads up on limit of Formtastic. I rewrote completely my form in a partial and get it working as before. However I am having a hard time with the js part. Any hint or code to put me on the right way ?